# Heroku and ClearDB error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, cleardb

I have a Ruby on Rails application with a mysql database (using the gem mysql2). Since Heroku runs postgres I followed this step in order to make it work:

```
$>heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite
$>heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
$>heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql2://my-url'
```

As described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb).

The problem is that I get this error on the last command:

```
Setting config vars and restarting xxxxxx-xxxxx-16407... !!!
 ▸    Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL.
```

And my application can't run:

```
2016-03-18T10:31:31.413121+00:00 heroku[run.1567]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-18T10:31:34.818303+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=xxxxx-xxxxx-16407.herokuapp.com request_id=236455b8-7a02-49f0-8e2e-a67341a81580 fwd="151.225.234.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-18T10:31:35.308136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=xxxxx-xxxx-16407.herokuapp.com request_id=974dab02-e914-42fb-ad96-5476e30e9d17 fwd="151.225.234.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-18T10:31:35.434538+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=xxxx-xxxxx-16407.herokuapp.com request_id=22bfdfd8-9cdf-4e3d-bb13-c616591bd91f fwd="151.225.234.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I have already execute bundle install and rake db:migrate on the heroku machine.

Do you know how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to heroku support I solved the problem!

Basically I needed to delete my old Database implementation before running the new one. Here's what I did:

```
$ heroku addons:destroy heroku-postgresql -a NAMEOFTHEAPP
```

And do again the procedure for installing ClearDB. Everything is working now!

Comment: ClearDB stayed installed after removing `heroku-postgresql`- just had to run the `heroku config:set DATABASE_URL` command again :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the old DB before adding the new DATABASE_URL by following command:

$ heroku addons:destroy heroku-postgresql

I will ask the name of the app. Or you can use directly

$ heroku addons:destroy heroku-postgresql -a NAMEOFTHEAPP